# Can i traverse a expression bodied member with an ExpressionVisitor?

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I have the following data structure:

```
class OrderLine : Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [CalculatedField]
    public decimal LinePrice {
        get => Quantity * LinePrice;
    }
}
```

I want to traverse the Expression of the LinePrice getter with an ExpressionVisitor. To build a request to a remote system.

Is there a way to (via reflection?) to access the expression bodied member getter's Expression?

Comment: No, expression bodied members are only syntactic sugar.

Comment: Can you provide documentation to confirm your statement and post it as an answer? I will gladly accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot traverse the `Expression` of expression-bodied properties, because they are not `Expression` objects. Expression-bodied properties are no different from other properties, except their syntax. Your property here:

```
public decimal LinePrice {
    get => Quantity * LinePrice; // did you mean UnitPrice?
}
```

is compiled into: (as is seen on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUOAEB5ATgEwKbIDIEsB26sA3rPGfCAMzz4Au8AkqvEfAObq0Dc8AzpzwC+sUuSrwMAYxwBbAIYAbeAEUArnLy0ctAJ4t2AvoeExRZcVNmL4AVTzaACshyT0+jtyOeTZitUvySrgETi5uJDDkUQb0ALwAfCrqmtp6AFTwweihrly+JoJAA=))

```
.method public hidebysig specialname 
    instance valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal get_LinePrice () cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal OrderLine::get_Quantity()
    IL_0006: ldarg.0
    IL_0007: call instance valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal OrderLine::get_LinePrice()
    IL_000c: call valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal::op_Multiply(valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal, valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Decimal)
    IL_0011: ret
}
```

which is the same code that would be generated, if you used a block-bodied property. And as you can see, there's no `Expression`s anywhere. You can try this on SharpLab. This shows that expression-bodied members are purely syntactic sugar.

If you want to traverse it as an `Expression`, you should actually declare an `Expression`:

```
// now you can traverse this with ExpressionVisitor
public static readonly Expression<Func<OrderLine, decimal>> LinePriceExpression 
    = x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice;

// to avoid repeating "Quantity * UnitPrice" again in the property getter,
// you can compile the expression and reuse it
private static readonly Func<OrderLine, decimal> LinePriceExpressionCompiled 
    = LinePriceExpression.Compile();

public decimal LinePrice => LinePriceExpressionCompiled(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. It answers my question and provides a decent alternative!